# How to retrieve a value when set as a default value?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, logic

Okay, so I know how to set a default value in a textbox:

```
<input type='text' size="2" name="QuantityAlbum1" id="QuantityAlbum1" value='1' onblur="chkValue('album1', this.value)"/>
<input type='text' size="2" name="QuantityAlbum2" id="QuantityAlbum2" value="1" onblur="chkValue('album2', this.value)"/>
```

So say I changed the value of the first textbox to three, it calls my method an gives a new price, however within my method I want to check if the second item has a quantity and if it does append it on to the existing price, so this my logic:

```
function newPriceTotal(chkObject, quantity){
      var newPrice=0;
      var albumQ1 = document.getElementById("QuantityAlbum1").innerHTML;
      var albumQ2 = document.getElementById("QuantityAlbum2").innerHTML;
        switch (chkObject)
        {

             case "album1":
             {
              newPrice =  4.99 * Number(quantity);
              if (albumQ2 != "")
                {
                  newPrice = newPrice + (8.99 * albumQ2)
                } 
                break;
              }     
        }  //end of switch
    return newPrice; 
}
```

So I have no problems until I get to:

```
if (albumQ2 != "")
```

when it reaches here it returns and empty string even though the default value is set to one and it displays a default value of one in the textbox.

Can anyone explain to why this is occurring and how I can go about fixing it?

Comment: `.value` and `.innerHTML` are different values. The element's `value` may be `1` while its `innerHTML` could be something else entirely or nothing at all.

Comment: it was a simple as that, LOL thank you @ElliotBonneville !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use *.value* instead of *.innerHTML*.